# cannot resolve method createstatement Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, database-connection

## Please make only for me to fix it

> Class Connection
>
> > I'm using https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.2.7/

```
public class ConnectionDB {
String ip = "192.168.1.103";
String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String db = "Andro";
String un = "abc";
String password = "1";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName(classs);
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + password + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
}
```

> And Class Login

```
 ConnectionDB con=new ConnectionDB();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        try {
            if (con == null) {
                alertDialog.setMessage("Cannot Access To Server");
            } else {
                String query = "Select * from Partner where lower(username)=lower('" + email + "') and password=N'" + password + "'";
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                if (rs.next()) {

                    alertDialog.setMessage("Success");

                } else {
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Fail");
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            z = "Exceptions";
        }
    }
```

> I searched google and did not find the answer
>   Sorry for my bad english

[Image Cannot Resolve method createStament](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oDBz.png)